# Android 13 WebView Instagram Login Issue (Blocked Cookie Pop-up)

Tags: android, facebook, webview, android-jetpack-compose, instagram-api

I've recently noticed that Instagram Login inside an Android App of mine is no longer working using a WebView, as the Instagram Login page no longer correctly displays a Cookie Popup, instead it just displays a greyed out and unresponsive webpage.

[image]

For reference even just loading https://www.instagram.com into a WebView using the same code has the same problem, the pop-up is not displayed and the webpage is greyed out and  unresponsive.

**Webview**

[image]

**Chrome**

In Chrome the pop-up appears correctly.

[image]

Here's the Jetpack Compose code for the WebView:

```
AndroidView(
      modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
      factory = { context ->
        WebView(context).apply {
          settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
          webViewClient = WebViewClient()
          loadUrl("https://www.instagram.com")
        }
      }
    )
```

The code was working fine for a longtime so guessing this change is a server side / Javascript change at Facebook's end? Anyone know how to get Instagram webpages working again inside a WebView?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution for Android 13 with Jetpack Compose 1.4.0. Simply use the WebView from the Accompanist library and Instagram (and the login page) loads normally again with Cookie Pop-up displayed for a user to accept and login using their account details.

Add Accompanist:

`implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-webview:0.30.0"`

And use this code instead for your WebView:

```
val webViewState = rememberWebViewState("https://www.instagram.com")

WebView(
  state = webViewState,
  onCreated = {
    it.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
  },
  modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
)
```